Mock object in view model
I am new to kotlin and I am trying to write unit test for a view model method which fetches user information using
val result = UserSvc().getUser()

How can i mock the method getUser()
My ViewModel looks like this:
My ViewModel class doesn't have any argument, it looks like this
class ViewModel: ViewModel(){
   private val userSvc = UserSvc()
   suspend fun getUser(){
     //
     val user = userSvc.getUser()
   }
}


it's not always the best solution to mock things mocking advantages comes for example
when you need to test legacy code or for example when there is no abstraction to use
(the real impl is used directly inside the class) so here i think you can just create a fake of UserSvc() where all users inside of it would be in a list and getUser will just filter that list and returns the correspondent user.
although here is a good mocking library for kotlin if you ever needed it :
https://github.com/mockk/mockk

To mock the getUser() method you can use a mocking framework like Mockito. Here's how you can do it:

Add the Mockito dependency to your build.gradle.kts or build.gradle file:


dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.11.2")
}



Write your unit test, mocking the UserSvc class and its getUser() method:


import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class YourViewModelTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var userSvc: UserSvc

    @Test
    fun testYourViewModelMethod() {
        // Mock the behavior of getUser() method
        `when`(userSvc.getUser()).thenReturn(/* your mocked user object or data */)

        // Create an instance of your view model, passing the mocked userSvc
        val viewModel = YourViewModel(userSvc)

        // Call the method you want to test in your view model
        viewModel.yourMethodToTest()

        // Assert the behavior or state of your view model after calling the method
    }
}



My ViewModel class doesn't have any argument, it looks like this
class ViewModel: ViewModel(){
private val userSvc = UserSvc()
suspend fun getUser(){
//
val user = userSvc.getUser()
}
}

You need to change the view model to accept parameters. Once you do that, to provide ViewModel to your activity you need to use ViewModel factory or dependency injection.
Alternatively you can pass the Usersvc object as an argument to the getUser function if its not getting used anywhere else in the Viewmodel.

The use Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned into Stackoverflow. Please, check the Stackoverflow policy about use chat gpt: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1 .

You can cascade constructors, so that your default ViewModel constructor calls one that takes a UserSvc as an argument. Then use that one in the test and mock it out.
(Without injecting the UserSvc dependency somewhere, you will not be able to introduce the mock.)
